# Table structure to achieve minute wise aggregates in SQL Server DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table structure where I have local date and count.

[image: Date Time with count]

I want to calculate sum of aggcount in 10 minute slots for 24 hours (these slots can be changed in future i.e. 2 min, 5 min, 7 min etc.), AM count, PM count and WholeDay count and store it in a table for reporting purpose.

Someone has proposed the following table structure where 1 and 2 represent 10 minute slot, so in 24 hours there are 144 10 minute slots so there will be 144 columns

[image]

Since this table is used for reporting purpose from a web application, we need to do minimum manipulations, so data is stored in the format it is required.

My concern with this table structure is :-

1. Since these slots may change in future, we might need more columns. If we have to calculate 1 minute count instead of 10 minute, we will need 1440 columns which is absurd.
2. Since every department has different working hours, so out of 144 columns for 10 minute slots, only 50 odd will have values for a particular day. so we are wasting lot of space.

**Note :-** As per my understanding, SSAS cubes might be the best possible solution to achieve these kind of calculations but this can not be done as of now.

Please suggest possible designs bases on your experiences?

Comment: If you ever want to perform comparisons between different times of day (say, which 10-minute slot is different than the average of everybody - outliers), that structure makes it difficult.  At 144 columns, it's also trivial to misplace or even _misread_ one (so I recommend dynamic SQL, if you don't have pivoting operators).  What's your volume of rows?  I'd prefer assembling the given structure on-the-fly from a normalized structure.  I hope these timestamps represent UTC time, as daylight savings time would kill this.

Comment: your existing design is ok. I agree with @Clockwork comment.Also  why write dynamic sql when you can create dynamic html table or do any other trick (pivot) in front end .

Comment: This is stored in this format because asp.net frontend needs this for reporting and my guess is that with dynamic sql and calculating this on fly will make it slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most table structures have some level of validity but I wouldn't suggest that table structure straight up, especially if your columns will change. It does solve the problem of counting different levels of detail in one row (department) though.

Here is one method of dropping a datetime into 'buckets':

First observe the original date and 'bucket date' (7 minute intervals in this example:)

```
SELECT 
LocalDate,
CONVERT(BIGINT,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LocalDate,112) + 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LocalDate,14),':','')
) / 700 * 700 As BucketDate
FROM YourTable
```

Now we can aggregate that into the buckets:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(BIGINT,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LocalDate,112) + 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LocalDate,14),':','')
) / 700 * 700 As BucketDate,
SUM(AggCount) As AggCount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 
CONVERT(BIGINT,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LocalDate,112) + 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),LocalDate,14),':','')
) / 700 * 700
```

Note these kinds of problems have two basic solutions:

1. Long complicated inline nested date and conversion functions (as shown here)
2. Use some kind of tally / time / date table to map your datetime to a bucket

We can also put this into a user defined function that you pass a time interval into. So your web app would just have to call

```
SELECT 
Department, Interval, AggCount 
FROM udfYourUDF(7)
```

Once you have a solution for this, your next step is to test it's performance. If your table isn't too big then you probably don't even have to pre-copy it into a table, you can select straight out of it.

Here is the SQL for AM/PM:

```
SELECT 
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LocalDate,109),2) As AMPM, 
SUM(AggCount) As AggCount 
FROM 
GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),LocalDate,109),2)
```

How do we stick those together? That depends on how your web app needs to show it.

Perhaps you should add your 'department' column to the example for completeness and also tell us if alternative data structures are an option.

Lastly, how up to date does the data have to be? Can it be 5 minutes old/1 hour old etc. If the latency required is not high then loading into a table becomes more practical.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I often use a `datetime2(0)` value that has been rounded down to the correct granularity. Example: `2014-02-23 12:34:56` becomes `2014-02-23 12:30:00`. You can then easily group by that value and even display it to end users.

You hinted that you might need different granularities in your summary table. You don't even need multiple tables for that requirement. Just add another column `Granularity TINYINT NOT NULL` as part of the primary key and define well-known values for that column. For example, you could have the following granularities:

```
1: Second
2: 10-Seconds
3: Minute
4: 12-Hour
5: Day
```

What you certainly don't want, though, are 144 columns for the 10-min slots. I'd only do that under extreme circumstances that are hard to imagine.

Comment: AM/PM aren't really separate granularities - you have a 12-hour granularity, with two windows.